# Django: Creating query set?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the following outcome `<EventQuerySet [{4: 10000, 5: 20000, [...]}]>`.

The way to "get" there is the following workflow:

1) Get each active event of the organizer

```
def organizers(self):
    return self.request.user.organizers

Event.objects.filter(
    organizer__in=self.organizers,
    status=EventStatus.LIVE
)
```

2) For each event > get all tickets that belong to that specific event. Especially, I need to get access to quantity & price of each ticket

3) Get the amount of tickets which are already sold

```
.annotate(
    sold_tickets=Count('attendees', filter=Q(attendees__canceled=False))
)
.order_by('organizer')
```

4) Now we have all the information we need to calculate the `max_remaining_gross_sale` per event:

**Example:**

**Event with pk 4**

Ticket 1: price_gross * (quantitiy - sold_tickets)

Ticket 2: price_gross * (quantitiy - sold_tickets)

**Event with pk 5**

Ticket 1: price_gross * (quantitiy - sold_tickets)

[...]

5) From all tickets per event we build the Sum an get the following result:
`<EventQuerySet [{4: 10000, 5: 20000, [...]}]>`

I didn't manage to build that QuerySet in a way that gives me the result from 5). Do you have any advice for me?

Here my models with the relevant fields:

```
class Ticket(TimeStampedModel):
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("Quantity"),
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100_000)],
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=TicketStatus.CHOICES,
        default=TicketStatus.ON_SALE,
        verbose_name=_("Status"),
    )
    price_gross = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("Price gross"), help_text=_("Includes tax if you set any.")
    )

class Event(TimeStampedModel):
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=EventStatus.CHOICES,
        default=EventStatus.LIVE,
        verbose_name=_("Status"),
    )
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(
        Organizer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='events'
    )

class Attendee(TimeStampedModel):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(
        Ticket, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='attendees'
    )  # PROTECT = don't allow to delete the ticket if an attendee exists
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='attendees'
    )
    canceled = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("Canceled"))
```

Comment: In your queryset `<EventQuerySet [{4: 10000, 5: 20000, [...]}]>`, I assume the `4` and `5` refer to event primary keys, but what do the `10,000` and `20,000` represent? Are they the sum of `price_gross * (quantitiy - sold_tickets)` across a given event?

Comment: Exactly right. Sum per event across all tickets in that specific event.

Comment: It seems like `Ticket` should have a fk to `Event` rather than `Attendee`. Unless the intention is that a ticket is not associated with a specific event? If you are open to making that schema change, I think it could simplify this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to calculate. If a ticket isn't tied to an event, then calculating `price_gross * (quantitiy - sold_tickets)` is going to over-count remaining gross revenue.  For a given ticket type, the quantity is constant. If Ticket Type 1 costs $1, and I have 1,000 of type 1, and I sell 900 at Event 1 and 10 at Event 10, your calc will say that there is a `max_remaining_gross_sale` of 100 for Event 1, and 990 for Event 2, when those two are actually drawing on the same pool of tickets (as you've modeled it here).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Hold on this - I left out your filter on cancellations

Based on my suggested edits, I think this should work:
`Event.objects.annotate(max_remaining_gross_sale=Sum(F('tickets__price_gross')*(F('tickets__quantity')-F('tickets__attendees')), output_field=FloatField())).values()`